# How to get key value pairs in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel

My column structure is as follows:

```
Column A:
SKU
AD01,
AD01,
AD01,
AD01,
AD02,
AD02,
AD02,
AD02,
AD03,
AD03,
AD03,
...

Column B:
empty

Column C:
SKU
AD01,
AD02,
AD03,
...

Column D:
ID
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
...
```

The idea is to match the SKU from Column A with the SKU from Column C and output the ID from Column D to Column B.

SKU's in Column C are unique.
SKU's in Column A are not.

What is the best way to do something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the formula in B2 will look like this:  you can then let Excel populate the formula in B3, B4 etc by dragging.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,C:D, 2, FALSE)
```

it means to look up A2's value in column C,D, once found, get the value in the 2nd column which is the value in column D.

Comment: For someone who's trying to pick key and value from columns that are not next to each other, you might have to change the third parameter above accordingly. eg: "2" for C:D --> but it would be changed to "3" if your keys column is C and value column is "E" instead of D compared to above answer.